# Is there any way to generate Inverted or taper geometry by using displacement?

Tags: modifiers, node-editor, geometry, displacement, height-map

Is there any way to generate reversed taper geometry? In other words: I'd like to generate the geometry you can see in the following picture just by using displacement modifiers or by using nodes:

[image]

**Q:** Is something like this possible by using displacement? The purpose of me thinking that this is nearly impossible is because if having a larger displacement on top, how am I supposed to depict a tapering gradient bellow it visually on a map? You can not show a dim gradient bellow a bright surface on a displacement map right?

*Note:* This question is not specifically about cones, it is about any type of displacement where I have a bigger surface on top of a smaller surface.

**For better illustration** consider a plane , Subdivide it 100 times and switch to cycles rendered mode with Displacement type set to Displacement and bump. The if i create the following Node tree , i can get the following result. The node tree is finding the Length of the origin and using a color ramp to manipulate the falloff of the resulting spherical gradient and passing through a displacement map to get the final result , but how can i taper at the bottom and have a bigger surface at the top?

[image]

Comment: What would your base mesh look like ? It is definitely doable, you need to figure out the maths. Is it worth it though ? Another good question :)

Comment: see , there is a tremendous amount of worth in doing anything procedurally , for practice , for more accountability and controll over dimensions , can you ggest some hint of how is that pissoble , an example height map?

Comment: I agree :) Was just asking if it could be achieved by another mean, but if it is for exercise, maybe you should try with more simple goals and work your way with that. But you still need to figure out what base mesh you are going to start with, because the maths involved will differ if you use a subdivided cube, a sphere or a plane. You should look up Simon Thommes, Just3DThings, Lance Phan on Youtube for instance

Comment: Maybe [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/170771/35559) will be nice to play with.. it's good for any surface of revolution, starting from a plane. In parrticular, it uses as its basis, your inverted cone.

Comment: @RobinBetts i want a type of displacement from nodes

Comment: @SHikhaMittal the link I gave you does it, but does other things too. I'll try to cook up a minimal illustrative example.

Comment: @RobinBetts reopened, answer away

Comment: @RobinBetts even i havent forgotten about this question , was trying to do somethin else till you give your " minimal illustrative example" 

Comment: @RobinBetts Waitin...

Comment: This is trivially possible by making a cylinder and displacing (negatively) the bottom verts.  How do you specify the bottom verts?  A texture mask is a good idea.  But that probably doesn't help you, right?  So you need more information about how you want it to behave in different situations than the example given.

Comment: @RobinBetts seems like you have a lot of nodes, so it is not same as the normal tapering effect where the tip is at the top , so lets say i use the vector math (Length) to create a circle and then changing the RGB curves to create a ramp , but how can this approach be used to make inverted cone or /......You get the idea :) but the problem is that the idea doesnt work , the rgb curves is not allowing me to make it like i want

Comment: Have to confess, this one's driving me nuts. I can do it, but not make it simple.

Comment: @RobinBetts should i start a bounty? by the way you can show the complex way

Comment: @SHikhaMittal, am not sure to understand well. Could you add some pictures indicating "starting from this, I want to have that"?

Comment: @ SHikhaMittal, thanks for the edit. @RobinBetts, don't get this " I can do it, but not make it simple"? Is that what we want to do, or am I bad here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbjlU.jpg

Comment: Hi, @lemon. Hoping you're the cavalry! If you have a relatively simple tree which does that without tearing the surface unduly, starting with a square plane, and preserving the square edges, please, yes! I'm probably just having a brain-f*rt! (Personal reason for those qualifications, I imagine it needs to be applied to quads on arbitrary surfaces, eventually.)

Comment: @RobinBetts, I agree that with square based surface, the displacement is crenalated.

Comment: @lemon I may or may not exactly want what you have , you get the idea , by accomplishing what i am asking will enable us to create all king of stuf and not just tapered stuff......

Comment: @RobinBetts true , u r on it for long

Comment: @lemon the picture that you added in your comment actually has it but the problem is that the cone is just a model demonstration , the purpose is to accomplish that can we produce different types of surface , not just a cone.....because with that a full half of opportunities in procedural work will be exposed

Comment: @SHikhaMittal, the nodes are defined specifically for a cone, but the displacement itself would be the same. The point is: we can specify displacements that go out of the base surface. But this is very basic: just a vector calculation.

Comment: @lemon so the calculations can be manipulated to get desired results for differnt shapes

Comment: @SHikhaMittal, I did simple thing here (just calculating a vector is the good direction) and not sure that node calculation could allow you to make "any" shape you want. Robin did a brillant example with the pawn Mine is much more simple. But as this "any shape" is not well defined, I can't make an answer. Though, here is the file so that you can progress on your subject:  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/A7xVzAW5/

Comment: @lemon , write the awnsere....

Comment: Hey @SHikhaMittal don't forget to manually award the bounty :). Or half of it will disappear into the void...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I write an answer as proposed to by @SHikhaMittal. Though, still not sure this is the wanted result.

As this is about "any shape", have used an image, like a decal, to drive the displacement.

[image]

The shape is colored with *"wireframe"* node, so that we can see the result of the displacement in term of geometry.

The nodes:

[image]

Bottom part is the decal used to drive the displacement scale. It is 0 outside of the image.

The middle line is to offset the normal around the mesh center. X and Y parts are scaled and added to the normal in order to drive this normal "outside".

Top part, the wireframe colors.

[image]

Remarks:

We can notice that the scaled and displaced part looses resolution, because we only keep a small amount of vertices and scale them.

The other [answer by Bruk](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/199396/19156), using another way to do it (scaling down a larger part along a cylinder) should avoid this issue.

Comment: Phew! Gordian knots are there to be cut! Indiana Jones draws his revolver...

Comment: @RobinBetts, I can't beleive you have not find a way to do this kind of thing.(happy to see *clutch* is not mentioned anymore ; ))

Comment: @RobinBetts, btw, what is your favorite work by Matisse? (nothing related to the subject here)

Comment: (All IMO, and breaking BSE rules just this once) The whole body of work, really.. Matisse never had the preternatural facility of a Picasso, so I always felt he put the work in.. he didn't get lazy. (Picasso did churn out some junk, sometimes..) And he had great access to his own spirit. If there's one thing he can be accused of, it's being cosy. He said as much, himself. So just to be contrary, today, I'll choose the _Piano Lesson_.

Comment: @RobinBetts, this one? https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Le%C3%A7on_de_piano And surely we don't have to choose about Matisse or Picasso.. Just appreciate them.

Comment: [This one](https://www.moma.org/collection/works/78908) Ohhhh... I'm not choosing! I'm absolutely gobsmacked by some Picasso.

Answer (score 4):

In case of tapers you can do it like this.
[image]

Comment: Hi, @Bruk ..Wrong way up.  :D.. the _tip_ of the cone should be on the plane, requiring vector, rather than simple displacement, because of the undercut.

Comment: @SHikhaMittal Hey man, don't be too hard on him :). I made the exact same answer and almost posted it. He's just trying to help :).

Comment: @JachymMichal ha , thats why i wrote "not being rude" , hey bro dont cry .......al BlenderERS are a family

Comment: @SHikhaMittal Please also remember, that rep points does not mean skill or value (this is just and mostly participation result).

Comment: @lemon yeah sory

Comment: @SHikhaMittal Take a look

Comment: @Bruk i might mark that as correct and i dont think using a cylinder is bad but just another favor can you bake the hight map for me please

Comment: Yay! That's better!

Comment: Yes, going larger to thiner can be a better way. The point is: how to spot (from "any shape") the vertices?